# cmd "There is no profile assign to the specific interface"

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line

I'm not really a tech savvy person and I really don't understand what I am doing. I'm just trying to connect to another secured network through cmd.

I've read on other tutorials to do this

> netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME interface="WIRELESS
>   NETWORK CONNECTION"

but I'm  very much confused.. SSID and Name should be the same, right?

I'm getting a result like this

> "There is no profile "WifiName" assign to the specific interface"

and sometimes this

> "One or more parameters for the command are not correct or missing."

I'm really confused now. Please help. Can you explain it to me with a layman's word? :( I'm not really good with tech jargons. Thank you!

Comment: [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_wlanConn) you have detailed descriptions of `netsh wlan connect` parameters. It describes what is the difference between `ssid` and `name` paramters. Moreover probably you shoud start with [adding wlan profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_wlanAddProfile) before you can connect using it.